# Can I create an excel function that compares 2 values and returns the cell of the larger value

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I am trying to go through a very long list of data and quickly compare. The data is for delivery days. I have a pivot table with the days of the week on the top and the stores with their size of delivery down the side. Some stores get multiple deliveries a week so it would show a number in two columns for the same row. I am trying to compare these stores that have multiple delivery days and see if they actually need multiple delivery days. For example, if a store has a 100 under Monday and 20 under Tuesday, that Tuesday delivery is not necessary and should be combined to Monday. My hope is that I can make a function that looks at all the stores and says, if one delivery day is less than 50% of the other delivery day, they should be combined. Ideally this function would return a list of the stores that violate these parameters so I can go through them manually. Is this something excel can do, and if not, what other program should I look into?

I have all the data broken up by store, and size of delivery categorized by what day of the week it gets deliveries.

[image: Here is my pivot table]

So for example, store 1 and 4 have only one delivery, store 6 is ok because it has two delivery days but the days are equivalent. But store 2 is where there is a problem.

Also, some stores get 3 deliveries so could the function also look at these and if 1 of these 3 days has less than 30% of the most day it flags it?

Comment: so max() and min(), and compare the difference (max() -  min()), but would a max chack be relevant so that the summ of all deliveries should not exceed X?

Comment: =LARGE() FUNCTION AS WELL

Answer (score 1):

To get a threshold for which each store should be flagged, you want to take the day with the most deliveries, and divide it by the number of delivery days. The formula in column I is:

```
=MAX(B2:G2)/COUNTA(B2:G2)
```

To flag a store, you want to check if the day with the least deliveries is below the threshold. The formula in column J is:

```
=MIN(B2:G2)<I2
```

[image]